# Efficiency: generic array vs object array

Tags: java, performance, generics

Suppose, you have to call very often operation `T get(int)` which returns an object from the underlying array. Basically, this can be implemented in two ways:

```
class GenericArray<T> {
    final T[] underlying;
    GenericArray(Class<T> clazz, int length) {
        underlying = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, length);
    }
    T get(int i) { return underlying[i]; }
}
```

and

```
class ObjectArray<T> {
    final Object[] underlying;
    ObjectArray(int length) {
        underlying = new Object[length];
    }
    T get(int i) { return (T) underlying[i]; }
}
```

The first one is using reflection, so it would be slower at creation time. The second one is using downcasting which introduces some overhead. Due of generic type erasure at runtime, there has to be some implicit casting mechanism.

So is it true, that these two are equal when it comes to `get(i)`?

Comment: Disassemble the bytecode and compare.

Comment: @chrylis No. The bytecode is about as relevant as the source code. Neither gets executed directly when it matters. `+++` I see I was wrong this time: When the byte is exactly the same, then it is relevant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's check the bytecode:

```
Compiled from "ObjectArray.java"
class lines.ObjectArray<T> {
  final java.lang.Object[] underlying;

  lines.ObjectArray(int);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #10                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0
       5: iload_1
       6: anewarray     #3                  // class java/lang/Object
       9: putfield      #13                 // Field underlying:[Ljava/lang/Object;
      12: return

  T get(int);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: getfield      #13                 // Field underlying:[Ljava/lang/Object;
       4: iload_1
       5: aaload
       6: areturn
}


Compiled from "GenericArray.java"
class lines.GenericArray<T> {
  final T[] underlying;

  lines.GenericArray(java.lang.Class<T>, int);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #13                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0
       5: aload_1
       6: iload_2
       7: invokestatic  #16                 // Method java/lang/reflect/Array.newInstance:(Ljava/lang/Class;I)Ljava/lang/Object;
      10: checkcast     #22                 // class "[Ljava/lang/Object;"
      13: putfield      #23                 // Field underlying:[Ljava/lang/Object;
      16: return

  T get(int);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: getfield      #23                 // Field underlying:[Ljava/lang/Object;
       4: iload_1
       5: aaload
       6: areturn
}
```

As you see, bytecode for `get` is identical.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49710202/3973077) proves that the two `get` methods are equivalent. Here is a bytecode free answer explaining how I understand the topic. Remember that generics in Java are implemented using type erasure. Loosely speaking this means that `T` is replaced by `Object` and casts are inserted where necessary (actually it's not always `Object` - if you write `class Foo<T extends Number> { ... }`, then `T` within the body of the class is replaced by `Number`).

This means that the code for your `ObjectArray` class is transformed into something like this

```
class ObjectArray {
    final Object[] underlying;

    ObjectArray(int length) {
        underlying = new Object[length];
    }

    Object get(int i) { 
        return underlying[i]; 
    }
}
```

Notice that there is no cast in the `get` method. The `(T)` is only needed to make your code compile. It has no impact at runtime, and can never throw a `ClassCastException`.

The code for the other class is transformed into something like this:

```
class GenericArray {
    final Object[] underlying;

    GenericArray(Class clazz, int length) {
        underlying = (Object[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, length);
    }

    Object get(int i) { 
        return underlying[i]; 
    }
}
```

So the `get` methods are equivalent. The only difference between the two classes is that reflection is used to generate the array, so it would result in an `ArrayStoreException` if you tried to store an object of the wrong type. Since this could only happen if you abused generics by using raw types anyway, it is probably not worth using reflection for this in most situations.